# Waiting for activity to settle

Tags: android, performance, google-maps-android-api-2

I have an AsyncTask that loads a ton of polygons on map.  The action to load the polygons on the map is triggered by a UI button click.

On initial load of my map the user has a standard map with no polygons, when they click the button to load polygons it runs in the async task, and takes about 3 - 5 seconds for the process to complete.  Not great but its a lot of data.

Once the user has clicked that button that state is saved and the polygons will automatically be loaded on the map the next time they enter the app.

This is where I start to run into problems.  If I shutdown my app and reload the map comes up and automatically loads the polygons.  Yet this load takes 20-30 seconds.

It seems if my map is up and I let the user decide to load (even if they click the button pretty fast), the polygons load fairly quickly.

Yet If I auto load the polygons it takes orders of magnitude longer.  So much so that in this case I get 'skipped frames' messages from the UI thread.

Does an activity or maybe a google map view take a few seconds to settle?  I know there is an event that gets fired when all map tiles are loaded, but I cannot wait for that cause it is not guaranteed to be called (ie not all tiles may load if disconnected).

Comment: Note, doesn't seem like a settle issue.  I added a sleep at the beginning of my background processing.  Up to 15 seconds, to give the activity and the map time to settle.  Still slower when I kick off the load programmatically, rather than from a user click.  Very strange...